# The number of simplicial and general $d$-polytopes with $d+3$ labelled vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, enumerative-combinatorics, triangulations

Micha Perles used Gale diagrams to compute the number of simplicial $d$-polytopes with $d+3$ vertices and of general $d$-polytopes with $d+3$ vertices. The computation can be found in Chapter 6.3 of Grunbaum's book, "Convex polytopes". My question is for formulas for the number of simplicial $d$-polytopes with $d+3$ **labelled** vertices and general $d$-polytopes with $d+3$ **labelled** vertices. The Gale-diagram technique should apply (and probably be easier) but I am not aware of this being done.

One motivation would be in trying to compute the number of simplicial d-polytopes, triangulations of $(d-1)$-spheres (and related non simplicial objects) with $d+4$ labelled vertices.

Answer (score 1):

With Ron Adin we worked out the answer for the simplicial case. **A)** All simplicial order types, **B)** simplicial polytopes, **C)** Neighborly polytopes ($d$ even):

$n=d+1$

**A)** 1 **B)** 1 **C)** 1

$n=d+2$

**A)** $2^{d+1}-1$,

**B)** $2^{d+1}-(d+3)$,

**C)** $\frac {1}{2} {{d+2}\choose {(d+2)/2}}$.

$n=d+3$

**A)**  $C  +1/2 \sum_{t=4}^n t! S(n-1,t)$.

**B)** $C'+  1/2 \sum_{t=4}^n t! S(n-1,t)$.

Where $C=2 S(n-1,2) + 6 S(n-1,3)$ and $C' = 6S(n-1,3) - 4(n-1)S(n-2,2) + (n-1)(n-2)$, and $S$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

**C)** $(n-1)!/2$.